# How to package fresh pasta and fresh pasta sauce

Tags: pasta, vacuum

I want to start selling my pasta sauce and fresh pastas (gnocchi and tortellini) in refrigerated compartments of departmental stores. Does any one know how stores package their sauces and fresh pastas? is it vacuum sealed or something else?

Comment: I think you should study the food-safety laws of the area you live in and obtain a permit to sell your food. Having said that, [here's an article](http://www.packworld.com/package-design/structural/fresh-pasta-maker-romances-long-shelf-life).

Answer (score 1):

In Italy fresh pasta (gnocchi, tortellini etc) are usually sold vacuum sealed in department stores... If you see rana fresh pasta (the most famous fresh pasta maker here in Italy, you can get some good ideas).
For what concerns sauce... the best way to sell it is in glass jars.

Comment: Paola, while I like your blog, simply linking to it without connection to the question or disclosing your affiliation may lead to your answer being deleted as spam - which would be a pity, IMHO. You are welcome to include your blog in your profile page and link to related articles in your blog (if you say that it's *your blog*) if they are relevant, though. I realize that you are new here, so if you have any questions on this policy, ask, preferrably on meta.